# how im getting this decode error everytime i take source code of Facebook Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How im getting this Decode error Everytime i take Source code of Facebook Python3 [Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIQtX.png)

Everytime i use selenium python 3 and Requests library to take output or view-source of a Website and i use read() or readlines() i get this Error any Solution please

my code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.facebook.com"
browser.get(url)
html = "view-source:" + url
browser.get(html)
response = requests.get(browser.current_url)
page_content = response.text
time.sleep(7)
file = open("facebook.html , 'w')
file.write(page_content)
file.close()
out = open("facebook.html , 'r')
output = out.read()
```

error is in Last Line :( already tried readlines() also..........

Comment: Please consider leaving your error in your question as text, en lieu of a jpg. Also, is this all of your code? The output in the image, just before the error, does not appear to reflect output from the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with quotation.and please ensures that your browser driver is in the path of execution.
See below modified working code. notice the closing quotation for the first argument  in the `open()` method. Also I have changed to use firefox driver as I don't have chrome browser. but should work the same way.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.facebook.com"
browser.get(url)
html = "view-source:" + url
browser.get(html)
response = requests.get(browser.current_url)
page_content = response.text
time.sleep(7)
file = open("facebook.html" , 'w')
file.write(page_content)
file.close()
out = open("facebook.html" , 'r')
output = out.read()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need `utf-8` as encoding while you open `html` file.
Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.facebook.com"
browser.get(url)
html = "view-source:" + url
browser.get(html)
response = requests.get(browser.current_url)
page_content = response.text
time.sleep(7)
file = open("facebook.html , 'w')
file.write(page_content)
file.close()
out = open("facebook.html , 'r',encoding='utf-8')
output = out.read()
```

Comment: @VladimirGaragulya You can accept and upvote the answer. If it solves your query.